# DIFFERENCE IN DAYS BETWEEN VARIABLE NUMBER OF ROWS

Tags: teradata-sql-assistant

I have this situation in a Teradata dataset:

```
ID                DATE1                         
134311784   14-2-2019   (first visit)           
134311784   7-3-2019    (second visit)          
134311784   22-3-2019   (third visit)           
234567891   10-2-2019   (first visit)           
234567891   17-2-2019   (second visit)          
234567891   22-2-2019   (third visit)           
234567891   18-3-2019   (fourth visit)
```

I expect this:

```
ID                DATE1          DIFFERENCE     
134311784   14-2-2019              0        NEW VISITOR
134311784   7-3-2019               21       --> (second -first ) = 21
134311784   22-3-2019              15       --> (third - second ) = 15
234567891   10-2-2019              0        NEW VISITOR
234567891   17-2-2019              7        
234567891   22-2-2019              5        ..
234567891   18-3-2019              24       ..
```

How do I accomplish this?
I tried with sub query but it does not give the desired result.

```sql
SELECT   t1.visit, t1.date1,T2.date1, abs( t2.date2-t1.date1) as difference
FROM data_want T1
left join data_want T2
on T1.visit=T2.visit
WHERE t2.date1 > t1.date1
```

[image: Data sets]

Answer (score 0):

No need for self-join, just an ordered analytic / window aggregate function

```
SELECT   t1.ID, t1.date1,
   t1.date1 - LAG(t1.date1,1,t1.date1) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t1.date1) difference
FROM data_want T1
ORDER BY t1.ID, t1.date1
```

Or `COALESCE(t1.date1 - LAG(t1.date1) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY T1.date1),0)` would give the same result (difference = 0 for first visit). Without the default clause or COALESCE, first visit would have NULL.

Answer (score -1):

I would guess you could try doing this this:

```
SELECT   t1.visit, t1.date1,T2.date1, DATEDIFF(t2.date1, t1.date1) t as difference
FROM data_want T1
left join data_want T2
on T1.visit=T2.visit
WHERE t2.date1 > t1.date1
```

Comment: thanks,i already tried that also.. but it gives an error: date1  does not match a defined datatype!!! (datediff(t2.date1....)

Comment: datediff syntax: DATEDIFF(day, t2.date1, t1.date1) as difference 
gives error Expected something between '(' and the 'day' keyword!

Comment: DATEDIFF is not a Teradata function